# How to redirect background mode (paused) app to App screen

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

Below is my code where i registering background mode service (play sound) when app is closed and running in background.

// register a background service. this JS will run when the app is backgrounded

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('pause',function(e){
        Ti.API.info("app was paused from the foreground");
        service = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({url:'bg.js'});
        Ti.API.info("registered background service = "+service);
});
```

My questing is how to redirect background mode app to running (normal) mode Application screen automatically after registerBackgroundService executes ?

Comment: You can't.  Only the user can launch an app into the foreground

Comment: what is alternate solution ? i want to notify user  whenever sound is play in App background-mode and user will get aware about this

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you want to do - How do you expect the sound to be played in background mode?  What is going to trigger it?  You should look at local notification (I am not sure how this is exposed through titanium but there must be a way).  If the user taps the local notification then your app will be returned to the foreground

Comment: I play sound whenever new local notification arrives in App and sound also plays when App is running in background mode. At that time exactly i want to redirect user to App normal screen or any-other alternate solution

Comment: Below is my code which explains how i play sound in my app
var player = Ti.Media.createSound({url:"alloy/solemn.mp3",
         allowBackground:true,
         idleTimerDisabled: true,
         });

Comment: You can play a sound by specifying it with the local notification.  If the user taps the local notification then your app will return to the foreground.  Your app can't return itself to the foreground because the user is in control.  They might be doing something and don't want to run your app.  Apps on iOS don't really "run" in the background; they are suspended and you have a few seconds to execute when they transition between foreground and suspended state, that is why I don't understand how you are triggering the playing of a sound.

Comment: should it require to enable push notification services from my Apple account ?

Comment: Push notification is an alternative to local notification if you want to initiate the notification from a server. You can use a 'silent push to execute code in your backgrounded app but it still won't bring the app to the foreground though.

Comment: ok thanks paulw for spending time
without registering push notification from apple account can we work with local notifications with ios and android device ?

Comment: Also please provide specific doc or code material if you aware about it

Comment: I don't know about Android and I don't know about Titanium as I only code in Objective C, but I presume that there is some module that provides UILocalNotification support for you.

Comment: Here you go http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS-method-scheduleLocalNotification